# How to loop over a list of different objects to run a Method of the same name ( and same data type) on them?

Tags: c#

I am making a chess game, I have Classes of pieces ( Rook, Knight...etc).
When game starts objects of pieces initiated and they are gathered in one list (`List<objects>`).
Every Class has a Method called (`availableMove`) Which return the same type but every class has different way of implementation.

All i want is a way to iterate over the List and use the method on them.

In a Magical world where everything runs as i want, this how it will look like:

```
foreach(var item in listOfDifferentObjects)
{
item.availableMove();
}
```

but this gives me this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Chess.Models.Pieces.Piece'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: Each of those classes needs to implement the same interface (or extend the same baseclass), which declares that method. Then each can have its own implementation

Comment: You need an interface

Comment: Thanks...
I am reading about it right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a base class for your chess pieces.

```
public abstract class ChessPiece
{
    public abstract void AvailableMove();
}
```

Then derive your specialized pieces from the base class.

```
public class Rook : ChessPiece
{
    public override void AvailableMove()
    {
        // ...do stuff.
    }
}
```

Then you can use a list of `ChessPieces` to iterate through.

```
foreach (var chessPiece in chessPieces)
    chessPiece.AvailableMove();
```

If your list has additional objects and it needs to have `object` as item type, you can filter the list using Linq.

```
foreach (var chessPiece in allObjects.OfType<ChessPiece>())
    chessPiece.AvailableMove();
```